# Is there a list of supported file types which can contain resources?

Tags: delphi, winapi, resources, file-type

I'm looking for a list of file types which can contain resources and can be loaded by [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [<strike>`LoadModule`</strike>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

I want to load resources using [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function where the first parameter is the handle to a module and I'd like to know what file types are supported (may contain resources and can be loaded by the [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [<strike>`LoadModule`</strike>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).

Footnote:
I'm working on a translation tool with resource support and I need this for file open dialog filter.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm looking for a list of file types which can contain resources and can be loaded by LoadLibrary and LoadModule functions.

You should not use `LoadModule`, it's for compatibility with 16 bits application. `LoadLibrary` is used to, well, load libraries: Executables and DLL's fit the bill. Since you want the information for your File Open dialog, I assume you're mostly interested in applicable file extensions. Unfortunately that's not easy, because EXE's and DLL's don't necessarily need to have the EXE and DLL extensions. For example the `SCR` extension is a popular extension for screen savers, but the actual file is a plane EXE. `BPL` is the extensions of Delphi's compiled packages, but those files are actually `DLL`'s as far as `LoadLibrary` is concerned.

In my opinion you should simply filter on EXE and DLL, but let the user open whatever they want. You'll only know if it's truly compatible with `LoadLibrary` if `LoadLibrary` fails or not.

Comment: .ocx .vxd .bpl and I guess there are more.

Comment: +1 and accept, about the `LoadModule` I missed that note, thanks. Anyway I've been using only `LoadLibrary`. I was looking for an official file type extensions which can contain resources, but you're right I'll stay at the `*.exe` and `*.dll` default filter. So I solve it simply with this filter `Binary files (*.exe;*.dll)|*.exe;*.dll;|All files (*.*)|*.*`. Thanks!

Comment: Even better, use LoadLibraryEx with LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE. That way you don't execute any code that might be triggered by a DllMain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using dll files with resources. function loadresource works fine with loadlibrary function. 
For example,

```
..
var
   LibHandle: THandle;
   Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
   LibHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar('MYDLL.DLL'));
   if LibHandle <> 0 then
   try
     Bitmap := Tbitmap.Create;
     Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(LibHandle, 'ICON16');  // ICON16 - Resource name, which contains bitmap with size 16x16
   ..
   except on E: exception do
     ..
   end;
..
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, as far as the [PE (COFF) specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119) is concerned, the extension of a "Portable Executable" file does NOT play any role! Even a file without an extension might be a valid file which could be loaded with LoadLibrary(Ex). As Prund correctly said "You'll only know if it's truly compatible with LoadLibrary if LoadLibrary fails or not.."! Potentially, any file (even a file named myfile.doc might be an "executable".