# InnoSetup's ignoreversion flag: For which file types?

Tags: inno-setup

InnoSetup has the `ignoreversion` flag for items in the `[Files]` section to specify that the file should be copied regardless of its version information. This is kind of the default that I would expect from a setup most of the time, yet it is not the default behaviour if it is not set. So I see this flag set in most setups for *every* file item, executables and non-executables alike.

I'm wondering what the file types are for which this flag makes any difference? Obviously .exe and .dll are affected, and .txt is not. Is there some definitive guide on this? I'd like to get rid of these extra flags on my file items if they serve no purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The general recommendation I always give is to absolutely always use `ignoreversion` on every file in `{app}`.

It causes no harm on files without resources (and potentially improves performance in that Inno doesn't have to waste time discovering that they lack resources), and is almost always what you want for app files (otherwise you can end up in some weird frankenstate with a mixture of files).

However for files installed outside of `{app}` (typically either `{sys}` or `{cf}`) you usually should not use `ignoreversion` and should instead only permit upgrades.  But YMMV.

(Note that special care may need to be taken for ensuring upgrades of common files outside of `{app}`, as only EXE and DLL files typically have version information, and even some of those may lack it or it may not be updated consistently, depending on the source of the file.  Other considerations also apply to common files, such as using `sharedfile`.)

(Promoted [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562633/innosetups-ignoreversion-flag-for-which-file-types/22567205?noredirect=1#comment34388438_22567205) to answer.)

Answer (score 1):

### For which file types is the "ignoreversion" flag meaningful ?

For those that can have Windows resources. Version information reading in Inno Setup falls deep down to Windows API so it's actually the system which determines from which files the version information can be read. Currently, the [`About Version Information`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic specifies the files, that can have version information briefly as:

> You can add version information to any files that can have Windows
>   resources, such as DLLs, executable files, or .fon font files.

Which narrows the list of possible files to the list of files that may contain resources. Unfortunately, there is no (and cannot be) a list of extensions of files, that might contain resources, because you can have a file with version information having some exotic file extension (I've [`asked for it`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8092169/960757) a long time ago).

So, there is no credible advice, for which files you should keep or remove this flag.

### Is the "ignoreversion" flag really intended ? When should I use it ?

More it makes me wonder, why to include the [`ignoreversion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=ignoreversion) flag. I would say it should be used rarely and carefully only there, where you are sure a possible downgrade of a certain file won't hurt. Without it, the Inno Setup compares version of the installed file with an existing one and replaces it when it's older, which is in my view the most wanted behavior.

Comment: We sometimes don't increase the version number of an executable but still give away or try ourselves a new setup build. If ignoreversion was not set, the setup would do nothing at all, unless the uninstall was called before. Also, if the user runs an older setup package, it should install that older application version instead of silently doing nothing at all. So to me, this flag is more useful than not setting it.

Comment: The general recommendation I always give is to absolutely always use `ignoreversion` on every file in `{app}`.  It causes no harm on files without resources (and potentially improves performance in that Inno doesn't have to waste time discovering that they lack resources), and is almost always what you want for app files (otherwise you can end up in some weird frankenstate with a mixture of files).  However for files installed outside of `{app}` (typically either `{sys}` or `{cf}`) you usually should not use `ignoreversion` and should instead only permit upgrades.  But YMMV.

Comment: @Miral i would love to upvote your comment as answer :)

Comment: @kwesoly: fair enough.  Reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The version flags refer to the version of your application installer package and not to the DLL version of a file shipped with the installer. Because of this .txt files also have a version and the 'ignoreversion' flag makes sense for any file within the installer package. It's up to the developer to trace and adjust the file updates between application versions using any of the InnoSetup provided flags.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. The question was about the `ignoreversion` flag, not about some *version flags*. What's more, plain text files cannot have version information hence the `ignoreversion` flag does not affect them in the way of checking file version. On the other hand, DLL libraries can have version information and the `ignoreversion` flag causes to check this. Your last statement *It's up to the developer to trace and adjust the file updates between application versions using any of the InnoSetup provided flags.* might be true but why do you need to say that ?

Comment: Think about version, like the version of the package/installer you create. Version is never the version of the file(DLL version) but the version of the package. All files within your installation package have the same package version and the installer does not care and does not know what is your DLL version. Imagine installer version 1.0. With the next update the installer gets version 1.1 and the TXT files within will be also marked as 1.1. This information is not stored within the files itself, but from InnoSetup inside the registry upon installation of your package/application.

Comment: You can run older version of the setup and if you specify `ignoreversion` flag for a `[Files]` entry, that file will be overwritten no matter what.